# How to validate current page with Tidy class

Tags: php

I am trying to validate the current page using the PHP `Tidy` class. But it is coming back valid every time, even when the current page has errors.

**PHP FILE**

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$tidy = tidy_parse_string($html);

if(tidy_diagnose($tidy))
{
    echo "This page has passed HTML validation";
}

else {
    echo "This page has NOT passed HTML validation";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation of `tidy_diagnose()`](http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.diagnose.php) states:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Which refers to the function `tidy_diagnose()` itself. To get the result of the operation, read [`$tidy->errorBuffer`](http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.props.errorbuffer.php) instead. If you prefer the procedural style, use `tidy_get_error_buffer($tidy)`.

If you only want to make sure there are not errors and warnings, you could also use the corresponding functions:

```
if (tidy_error_count($tidy) == 0 && tidy_warning_count($tidy) == 0) {
   // nothing to complain
}
```

Comment: I have used this, but this outputs a list of errors/warnings from the documentation I got the impression I could call tidy_diagnose to get a success/failure on whether it was valid or not

Comment: You can achieve that using the `*_count()` functions, see update.